# Champions League R16 draw in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

The Champions League round of 16 knockout is a stage of the competition where 16 european football teams are drawn against each other in a 8 game match. There are a few rules: 
- Countries from the same country must not be drawn against each other.
- Teams that have played before on the group stage must not be drawn against each other.

UEFA separates the teams into two pots:
- Teams that have won the group on the round before.
- Runners up from the round before.

A team from pot 1 is drawn and then pot 2 is adjusted to contain only teams according to the rules above.

There is a simulator online that shows exactly like the draw is performed:
https://draw.inker.one/#/cl/ko/2019

This seems fairly easy to implement in C# however, with the way I have tried, near the end of the draw there are situations where the draw can become stuck. And that's the part I would like some help.

For instance. The draw is aproaching the end and...
- There are three teams on pot 1 to be drawn: Barcelona, Juventus and Liverpool
- Three teams on pot 2: Real Madrid, Man City and Benfica

Juventus is selected from pot 1. That leaves Real Madrid, Man City and Benfica as choices on pot 2. Benfica is drawn, so Juventus will play against Benfica.
Next we pick Barcelona from pot 1. Man City is the only possible choice (as Real Madrid and Barcelona are from the same country), so a Barcelona vs. Man City is drawn.
This leaves Liverpool and Real Madrid alone. But they have played before in the group stage, making the draw violating the rules.

Can someone help implementing this in C#?
I'm not sure which algorithm is needed to find the available teams in each phase of the draw.

Comment: You need to check in the other direction: Real Madrid cannot face either Barcelona or Liverpool. So it would be directly Madrid-Juventus.

Comment: agree, but that is a simple example. there are times that my choice in step 1 will only impact the draw two steps later...

Comment: You'll have to use backtracking. That is, whenever you have a choice of multiple teams, record your options and the choice you made. Later on, if you get stuck, rewind to the latest choice point and make another selection. If there are no choices left at a particular rewind point, go back to the previous one, and so on.

Comment: that would be a good solution if I don't show the draw being performed and only the end result. In my application I would like to present the draw as it was live, with each option being drawn, and not rewinds. like you see in the simulator I provided above.

Comment: You have to compute at each stage of the draw with the existing teams in each pot as to a selection leaves the simulation in a resolvable state for all the remaining teams. For example, as you mentioned if juve and benfica are drawn then that can lead to an invalid state. What you can do is the team chosen from pot 1 (i.e. Juve) then you need to resolve the draw such that you have a candidate team(s) from pot 2 and choose from those (i.e. a sub-group within pot 2)

Comment: Author here. Can I see your code?